# Trouble With FullCalendar 4.X and RRule Plugin Using Script Tags and Browser Globals Method

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, rrule

I'm trying to use FullCalendar 4.3.1 with rrule.js using script tags. According to [https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin][1]:

> "If you are using  tags and browser globals, you must ensure
>   the original non-plugin rrule.js dist file from the rrule site is
>   included on your page first."

Which I've done. In my calendar initialization JS I have:

```
/*js/myCalendar4.js*/
$(
    function(e) {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        _parentCalendar =   new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,   
                                {
                                    plugins     :   ['interaction','dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'rrule'],
                                    selectable  :   true,
                                    header      :   {
                                                        left    :'prevYear, prev',
                                                        center  :'title',
                                                        right   :'today, next, nextYear'
                                                    },
                                    dateClick   :   function(dInfo) {
                                                        swal({
                                                            title   :   "Calendar Date Click",
                                                            text    :   dInfo.dateStr,
                                                            icon    :   "info"
                                                        });
                                                    },
                                    select      :   function(dInfo) {
                                                        swal({
                                                            title   :   "Calendar Date Selection",
                                                            text    :   dInfo.startStr + " to " + dInfo.endStr,
                                                            icon    :   "info"
                                                        });
                                                    },
                                    eventClick  :   eventClickHandler,
                                    eventDrop   :   eventDropHandler,

                                    defaultView :   'dayGridMonth',
                                    weekends    :   true,
                                    timeZone    :   'America/New_York',
                                    eventLimit  :   true,
                                    eventLimitText  :   "hidden events",
                                    events      :   [
                                                {
                                        title:  'My RRule Recurring Event',
                                        rrule:'DTSTART:2019-10-29T05:30;FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=5',
                                        duration    :   '10:00'
                                    }
                                                    ],
                                    loading     :   function(isLoading) {
                                                        if (isLoading)  {
                                                            calBlock("Loading calendar events ...");
                                                        }
                                                        else    {
                                                            calUnblock();
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                    eventRender :   function(eventInfo) {
                                                        console.log("Rendered Info: ", eventInfo);
                                                    }
                                }
                            );
                    _parentCalendar.render();

                }

);




function calBlock(messageText)  {
    $("body").block({message: messageText});

}


function calUnblock()   {
    $("body").unblock();
}



function failureMethod(x)   {
                    calUnblock();
                    swal({
                        title   :   "Calendar Retrieval Error!",
                        text    :   x.message + "!",
                        icon    :   "error"
            });
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<title>FullCalendar 4.3.1</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webtools/JSCentral/JQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/core/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/daygrid/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/timegrid/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/interaction/main.js"></script>

<script src="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/rrule/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/rrule/rrule.js"></script>

<script src="js/sweet-alert/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myCalendar4.js"></script>
<script src="js/calendar4_action_handlers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/blockUI.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweet-alert2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webtools/JSCentral/JQuery/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/balloon-tooltip.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">

<link href="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/core/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/daygrid/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="js/fullcalendar/4.3.1/packages/timegrid/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.qtip.css">
<link href="css/calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweet-alert2.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to successfully load/display the calendar and work with it except for loading the test event containing the rrule recurring instruction. I get an error in the debugger saying it can't load the plugin file. FullCalendar 4.3.1 seems to come with a JS script to include: 4.3.1/packages/rrule/main.js. So, I'm wondering which one should be used to accommodate RRule. I tried removing the reference to 'rrule' in the plugin section. But, the event still doesn't load. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will re-quote the same fullCalendar documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin which you mentioned in your question, but I will use bold text to highlight one word in particular:

> If you are using  tags and browser globals, you must ensure
>   the original non-plugin rrule.js dist file from the rrule site is
>   included on your page **first**.

I think your mistake is simply including it second (after the fullCalendar file) and not first. The fullCalendar plugin script will no doubt check for the existence of the rrule.js library. Since it can't find it, it will fail to load.

Don't forget that a browser loads and executes each script block *immediately* as it parses each script tag, and it does so sequentially in the order the tags appear in the HTML markup.

Comment: This goes to show how the simplest things can trip you up. Thanks for you answer.